# NSLayoutConstraint with constraintsWithVisualFormat

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to use constraintsWithVisualFormat in my app but have encountered a problem that I can't figure out. I am adding a UIView subclass into a UIScrollView programatically and trying to avoid setting the frame.

I want to use constraintsWithVisualFormat to make the view fill its superview with 20px padding around the edge. The code below shows my current implementation which does not show up when I run the app. If I hard code the width and height properties then it appears.

```
[targetView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[targetView]-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(targetView)]];

[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[targetView]-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(targetView)]];
```

I thought this implementation would give me a view that sits in its superview with 20px margin all the way round.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong